# Change custom cell image color when selected in uitableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uitableview

I have a custom cell with imageview and label.When user selected a particular cell in the tableview I want change the image color or tint.
I managed to change the color of the label , but dont know how to do with the image. Any ideas?

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

         static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MenuCell";

        MenuTableViewCell *cell = (MenuTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = [[MenuTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
           // cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        }


        cell.lblTitle.text = [[_items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:@"title"];
        cell.imgIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[_items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:@"image"]];
        cell.lblTitle.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.839 green:0.682 blue:0.047 alpha:1];
       cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        return cell;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be changing the cell data inside your MenuTableViewCell custom class. There will be a methods in there that control the selected, highlighted state. The method will look something like this example,

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
if (selected) {
    //Change the text colour & image 
} else {
    //Change it back to whatever is was
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change cell image when you selected a cell. You can draw current image with a `tintColor`. See below code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MenuTableViewCell *cell = (MenuTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Change cell image color
    UIImage * image = [cell.imgIcon.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    cell.imgIcon.image = image;
    cell.imgIcon.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Your tint color
    [cell.imgIcon tintColorDidChange];
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, i had a mistake with users names, i edited my answer and add you to greetings.

Answer (score 1):

In the method `tableviewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath` write this code

//Edited to the correct syntax

```
{
  MenuTableViewCell *cell = (MenuTableViewCell *)[tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your image name when you want to change to selected"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is the following:

In the method tableviewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
MenuTableViewCell *cell = (MenuTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.imgIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your image name when you want to change to selected"];
```

Saheb Roy's answer put me on the right track but cellAtIndexPath has to be replaced by cellForRowAtIndexPath.

EDITED: in the above code what was being done was to have two different images and change them depending on whether the cell was selected or not.

Combining the answers given by Saheb Roy, longpham  and Devster101 finally i added the following code in custom cell class MenuTableViewCell.m:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if (selected) {
        UIImage * image = [_imgIcon.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        _imgIcon.image = image;
        _imgIcon.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.839 green:0.682 blue:0.047 alpha:1];
        [_imgIcon tintColorDidChange];

    } else {
       UIImage * image = [_imgIcon.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        _imgIcon.image = image;
        _imgIcon.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [_imgIcon tintColorDidChange];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the edit, yeah am on a windows pc so u can understand ;)

Comment: You want to change cell image color but this code only changed cell image by another image.

Comment: You're absolutely right , it was a temporary solution but not ideal.

Comment: I edited with the final code changing the tintColor of the image.